# Why do I get an undefined reference( to `glColor3f' ,for example) when I compile a program in c?

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

I'm compiling an example program that uses opengl in ubuntu (linux). A short snippet of the code is the following:

```
 #include <stdlib.h> 

 #include <GL/glut.h>


 void createBox( GLfloat centroX, GLfloat centroY,
                       GLfloat corR, GLfloat corG, GLfloat corB )
 {
    /* Cor  */

    glColor3f( corR, corG, corB );
```

I've installed all of the packages to develop in opengl (in ubuntu), namely:

```
freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa
libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev
```

I compile the example like this:

```
gcc -lGL   CG_ex04.c -o main
```

and I get the following

```
/tmp/ccDWmJDZ.o: In function `createBox':
CG_ex04.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `glColor3f'
```

and other errors along the same line.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanx in advance for any help.

Comment: This has everything to do with your compiler, and not the library you use. Please remove the opengl and glut tags :-)

Comment: Fixed the tags and title. Please remember this next time you post a question. Tags are meant to be *relevant to your problem*, not to be used just because your program uses a particular API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `gcc -o main CG_ex4.c -lGL`. The correct order of gcc parameters is important.

Comment: damn it, that was it, although it didn't work at first, I stil had to add '-lglut' to the command line, but now it works like a charm. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try including GL/gl.h as well as glut. Kind of weird though, since glut actually includes both gl.h and glu.h.