# Why does my program fail to link?

Tags: gcc, linker-errors

I'm doing a opengl program, and found an example that does what I want, but when I try to compile it, using
`gcc -o picksquare picksquare.c -lglut`
I get:

```
/tmp/cchE9Z0Y.o: In function `pickSquares':
picksquare.c:(.text+0x41d): undefined reference to `gluPickMatrix'
picksquare.c:(.text+0x442): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
/tmp/cchE9Z0Y.o: In function `reshape':
picksquare.c:(.text+0x508): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And the code example is here:
http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/redbook/picksquare.c

Thanx for your answer guys, but invoking with -lglu says it can't find glu, and invoking with -lGL gives the same undefined reference. What is this glu? Does anyone know?

Comment: You're probably missing some other libraries needed in addition to glut http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/2736/

Comment: Again, linking problems has nothing to do with opengl or glu. Please remove those tags. As you obviously use gcc, 'gcc' would be a better tag replacement. Just because your program uses $API doesn't mean that the API tag is relevant for the question. Stop abusing tags this way.

Comment: Nevermind, I did it for you. Just remember this next time you post a question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please stop making duplicate questions. This is is a linker problem exactly like you last question you asked Nov 14th: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4179079/95077 The only difference is that you get unresolved symbols to another library.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gcc filename_here -lglut -lGLU
```

This should work fine. The last word in the above sentence is *lGLU* (not one but l for lion) .

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling functions in the GLU library (which is not the same as GLUT), without linking to it.

Add `-lglu` to your command line.

Note that the functions failing have `glu` as their prefix, not `glut`.

If adding -lglu gives you a new error, that might mean you development system doesn't have the GLU library installed. It's an optionalal library independent of OpenGL, so just because you have installed development support for OpenGL there's no guarantee that you also have it for GLU.

Comment: If i do that, I get:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglu
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the necessary libraries installed *or* you need to point your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a correct location to pick up libglut.so.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for `gluOrtho2D` & co. you have to link against libGL, which means you have to add a `-lGL` switch on your command line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem, I wasn't adding the glu library to the gcc compiler, addind '-lGLU' solved the problem. Thanx anyways guys!!